# How to change LinkedList head pointer globally and not locally

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have TWO implementations of this.

Why does this particular implementation NOT work? I have a pointer to a pointer and im changing the inside point but it doesn't retain the change in the main function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int value = 4;
    Node* next;
};

void insertFront(Node*, Node**);

int main(){

    Node head;
    head.value = 32;
    head.next = nullptr;

    Node** headptr = new Node*;
    (*headptr) = new Node;
    *(*headptr) = head;
    (*headptr)->value = 32;//redundant, I know
    (*headptr)->next = nullptr;//redundant, I know
    cout << head.value << endl;
    insertFront(new Node, headptr);
    cout << head.value << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void insertFront(Node* newHead, Node** head2){
    cout << "Inside before swap " << (*head2)->value << endl;
    newHead->next = *head2;
    *head2 = newHead;
    cout << "Inside after swap " << (*head2)->value << endl;
}
```

Why does this one work? Can someone please explain IN DETAIL the pointer magic going on? I have a vague idea but im still a little bit confused. I understand that using a pointer to the head pointer allows you to change the head address globally but it's still a little bit cloudy. Can someone please clarify, what is going on with these pointers in both implementation?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int value = 4;
    Node* next;
};

void insertFront(Node*, Node**);

int main(){

    Node** head = new Node*;

    (*head) = new Node;
    (*head)->value = 32;
    (*head)->next = nullptr;
    cout << (*head)->value << endl;
    insertFront(new Node, head);
    cout << (*head)->value << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void insertFront(Node* newHead, Node** head2){
    cout << "Inside before swap " << (*head2)->value << endl;
    newHead->next = *head2;
    *head2 = newHead;
    cout << "Inside after swap " << (*head2)->value << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hint, convert code to use pointer reference, instead of pointer to pointer. That might lead to enlightenment. Then you can convert that back to pointer to pointer to make sure you got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both implementations are using double-indirection wrong, and both leak memory. You're question seems more about double-indirection than just about what works and what doesn't (whether you realize it or not). Its a C question, and though also applicable in C++, it is less so with that language because reference parameters make this somewhat easier (arguably).

I could simply say "use references to pointers" (which you could do), but that would be like you saying "why doesn't my car work?" and me answering "because this car over here will work". So I will provide a C answer (much to the dismay of my own common sense, as I can feel the furnaces firing up from the flamethrowers about to be sent my way). If I have time, I will include the C++ answer (using references), but no guarantees on that.

---

Pointers to pointers are no different than any other pointer type. All pointer types are types who's variables are defined to "point" to something of that type (I know, its repetitive and trivial, but bear with me here). The trivial example:

```
void foo(int x) 
{ 
    x = 5; 
}
```

obviously doesn't change `x` on the caller side, and you seem keenly aware of that. If you want to change an in/out parameter using pointers, you need to declare the formal parameter to be a pointer-to type, dereference said-pointer parameter within the function body, and pass the address from the caller. Ie.

```
void foo(int *p)
{
    *p = 5;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    foo(&x);
}
```

The truth is parameters are all pass-by-value in C, *even pointer parameters*.  Yeah, read that again. You say what? Seriously. Its true. It just so happens the "value" you're passing is an *address* rather than the value within some variable, and in so being  as such, the receiver must be something that is prepared to take, and manipulate, data via that address: a pointer.

Now. **Pointers to pointers are no different.** Pointers to pointers hold addresses of (wait for it...) *pointers*. Just like our first example, this:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}

vod foo(Node* ptr)
{
    Node *p = new Node();
    p->data = 0;
    p->next = ptr;
    ptr = p;
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = nullptr;
    foo(root);
}
```

**won't work**. You can fix this several ways. One way is using a pointer-to-pointer (the C way). Another uses a *reference to pointer* (the C++ way).

First the C way, which demonstrates the whole mantra of passing something by address means declaring the parameter to be a pointer-to type (in this case a pointer to pointer type), and passing the address of the thing to modify:

```
void foo(Node** ptr)
{
    Node *p = new Node();
    p->data = 0;
    p->next = *ptr;
    ptr = p;
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = nullptr;
    foo(&root); // LOOK: passing address of our root pointer
}
```

Do you see how, just like in our trivial example using `int` and `int*`, we have to pass the *address* of the thing we're modifying to a function that takes a pointer-to-type? In this case the "type" is, itself, a pointer type.

Now, arguable, the C++ way using a reference is *trivial* by comparison, but IMHO it isn't as clear what is going on, only because there is literally a **single character difference** between the version that doesn't work and the version that does. Look at this:

```
vod foo(Node*& ptr) // LOOK added &
{
    Node *p = new Node();
    p->data = 0;
    p->next = ptr;
    ptr = p;
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = nullptr;
    foo(root);
}
```

Notice how **everything else** in this is *identical* to the version that does *not* work. Everyone has their preferences, and knowing what to look for allows me to use either method, but I can see why some have such difficulty writing and debugging what is essentially double-indirection code hidden in a reference type.  Some engineers prefer to send *all* their out-params as pointer-to types, and I'm generally one of them.

---

**Peeling Back Your Code**

After all of that, lets peel back your code and see where things go to hell. I'll dissect the one that does *not* work, and hopefully you can see why *neither* version is honestly very good:

First your type:

```
struct Node
{
    int value = 4;
    Node* next;
};
```

Nothing horridly questionable here. The default value assignment in the structure definition. This will puke on non-current-day C++, so likely throw that out for now. If you want a default value, make a constructor (which you should have anyway to ensure all members are properly initialized to *something*):

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node* next;

    Node(int val = 4)
        : value(val)
        , next()
    {}
};
```

Ok. Next up..

```
void insertFront(Node*, Node**);
```

You seem to want to use a pure node interface. Most people writing a linked list would do this:

```
void insertFront(Node** ppRoot, int value);
```

but we'll go with your version for now. The actual implementation of this:

```
void insertFront(Node* newHead, Node** head2)
{
    newHead->next = *head2;
    *head2 = newHead;
}
```

is correct. Yes it could orphan anything previously being pointed to by `newHead->next`, but that doesn't seem to be a concern of yours, so we go with it for now.

Finally the torrent: `main()`.

```
int main()
{
    Node head;
    head.value = 32;
    head.next = nullptr;

    Node** headptr = new Node*;
    (*headptr) = new Node;
    *(*headptr) = head;
    (*headptr)->value = 32;//redundant, I know
    (*headptr)->next = nullptr;//redundant, I know
    cout << head.value << endl;
    insertFront(new Node, headptr);
    cout << head.value << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This has *multiple* issues. First, your mixing dynamic nodes with non-dynamic nodes.

```
Node head;
head.value = 32;
head.next = nullptr;
```

**Bad idea**. This is no reasonable way calling code (in particular *cleanup* code that deletes each node from the list), has any clue whether something being pointed to is dynamic or not. **Don't do that.**. Using the constructor version of `Node` from above, this should simply be:

```
Node* head = new Node(32);
```

Next you're dynamically allocating a *pointer*; (not a Node; a *pointer*)

```
Node** headptr = new Node*;
```

**Bad idea**. there is no need to do that at all. You already have a pointer variable to your list head (its called, not-coincidentally, `head`). This appears all to be a setup for invoking the insertion function. To do that, *everything* from `Node** headptr = new Node*;` on down can simply be replaced with this:

```
insertFront(new Node(10), &head); // LOOK: passing address of head pointer
cout << head->value << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly the kind of detail I was looking for. I'm headed into my sophomore year in college and im looking to get some nice internships so i've been brushing up on my C++ and have been half confused about pointers and dynamic memory allocation but now I seem to be finally understanding. Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using your pointers is so, so wrong.

Let's look at this code:

```
Node** headptr = new Node*;
(*headptr) = new Node;
*(*headptr) = head;
(*headptr)->value = 32;//redundant, I know
(*headptr)->next = nullptr;//redundant, I know
cout << head.value << endl;
insertFront(new Node, headptr);
cout << head.value << endl;
```

Let's first clean up this code a bit. There is no reason to allocate a `Node *` on the free store (using `new`), and then reference it through a `Node **`. It can and should simply be a local variable and referenced directly. To do that, we replace `Node** headptr = new Node*;` with simply `Node *phead`, and replace all instances of `(*headptr)` with merely `phead`:

```
Node* phead;
phead= new Node; // #2
*phead= head;    // #3
phead->value = 32;//redundant, I know
phead->next = nullptr;//redundant, I know
cout << head.value << endl;
insertFront(new Node, &phead);  // here we are passing the address of phead so that insertFront() can modify it
cout << head.value << endl;
```

Now look at this code carefully. You allocated space for a new `Node` on line 2, and made `phead` point to it. You *copied* the contents of `head` into this new `Node` on line 3. Then your `insertFront()` call modified a newly allocated node and set `phead` to point to that new node instead. At no point did any pointer *ever* point to `head`, and its value is never touched; when you check `head.value`, of course they remain the same.

Comment: Thank you!!. Honestly, if I could, I would pick both answers as the best but that's not what matters. What matters is that I'm starting to understand and you helped a whole lot. Thank You.